# Why does my below IF statement not display the results I am looking for?

Tags: php

I have two columns in my customer_profile table, "birthdate" and "gender". I'm suppose to detect if the user has complete their profile. However by using the conditions below, I'm not able to check if the customer has completed their profiles. It just returns "Profile Complete".

I tried changing the condition "&& to ||" and "|| to &&" and all to "&&" but it returns unexpected results.

The reason that there are so much conditions is because sometimes the customer doesn't fill in the data or leave it blank or keyed in "0" in the gender field or birthdate field. If there were only two conditions, I would not have to face this problem.

Below is my code comparing those two columns. All I want to check is if the customers data is not empty; NULL or 0 on these two columns.

```
$sql_stmt = "SELECT customer_id, first_name, email, phone, birthdate, gender FROM customers
                        WHERE customer_id = 1 LIMIT 1";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $sql );
extract($row);

if(($birthdate == '' && $birthdate == NULL && $birthdate == '0000-00-00') || ($gender == '' && $gender == 0 && $gender == NULL)){
     echo "Profile Not Complete";
} else { 
     echo "Profile Complete"; 
}
```

Comment: Tell me, how can a variable be an empty string AND null AND the string '0000-00-00' at the same time? You need ORs instead of ANDs there.

Comment: Well, `$birthday` cannot equal ***all of these values at once***. So each of your `&&` checks must always be `false`.

Comment: Some of the customers indeed has all these three values in those columns, the data is messed up because of different person who write this program and that's why it stores different data in these two columns.

Comment: A single column cannot contain three values!

Comment: @deceze The first customer might have "0", the second customer might have an NULL, the third customer might have a blank field. The customer_id can be other values for different customers. That's why I need a condition that checks all...

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing those variables to what you actually want them to be instead of to all those things that they could be but are nonsensical? E.g. `if(!in_array($gender, [%all those political correct genders%]) {...}`.
Currently, you would need to update your code for every nonsense your users can come up with.

Comment: I get that. What you fail to see is that *a single cell* cannot be all these things *at once*. It is *either* this **or** that **or** the other, not all of them.

Comment: @deceze got it, thanks

Comment: for multi values do not use && operator.. use OR operator

Comment: Guys, see my answer, this is actually a valid question. I think we should stop the downvotes.

Comment: thanks @Asryael for understanding. i dont even know why the downvotes. I'm facing a real situation here.

Comment: @nodeffect use `empty()` function and you don't have to take care with the tons of invalid values that you get. See my answer

Comment: @Marcos Don't use `empty($var)` if you really just mean `!$var`. See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Comment: @deceze I read that and after read it I think equal than before. I will use `empty()` in similar cases like this. It's easy, comfortable, bulletproof, and it is designed for this purposes. `!$var` is only the negation of the `$var` , not a comprobation of if it's empty with all values. See the values that returns true in empty function: http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php

Comment: @Marcos Have you *really* read it? The only reason `empty` exists is to do the same thing as `$var == false`, which is the same thing as `!$var`, without triggering a warning if the entire variable is not set. `!$var` is ***always*** exactly equivalent to `empty($var)`, except for the additional error suppression. And exactly for that reason (error suppression), you should not use `empty` unless you explicitly intent to. See the comparison table at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php (compare `empty` vs. `boolean if ($x)`).

Comment: Error surpression is fine to work with `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: @Marcos Yes, in the case of working with `$_GET`, you likely want error suppression, since you cannot ultimately control the existence of values inside `$_GET`. However, here you have absolute full control over the existence of your variables, there is no legitimate case where the variables *might not be defined*, because if they're not defined that'd point to a bug in your app. For this reason, you ***want*** error reporting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be like this:

```
if(($birthdate == '' || $birthdate == NULL || $birthdate == '0000-00-00') || ($gender == '' || $gender == 0 || $gender == NULL)){
     echo "Profile Not Complete";
} else { 
     echo "Profile Complete"; 
}
```

That means:

> If the group $birthdate is empty or null or 0000000, or gender is empty or zero or null...

### EDIT

I recommend to use this conditional way:

```
if(empty($birthdate) || empty($gender)){
     echo "Profile Not Complete";
} else { 
     echo "Profile Complete"; 
}
```

See more about `empty()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: In addition to this a default value in the database can further improve since the result will always be the same. But the best would of course to have a check on the signup page in order not to allow incomplete registrations.

Comment: It would also be nice to incorporate those checks into a method returning a boolean, and naming those methods clearly and logically, like `function is_date_valid($date) { return !($date == '' || $date == NULL || $date == '0000-00-00'); }` or something. That would improve legibility.

Comment: Note that `empty` won't match `0000-00-00`, but arguably you should never have this kind of value in your database to begin with...

Comment: @klaar with OOP PHP all is better. You can make a class with some methods and then call them. But OP doesn't have that code and I only edit his code

Comment: @deceze yes, you're right, in the database should be null value, not 0000-00-00 that's incorrect

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Indeed so, but if we see nasty old school procedural code like this, we should at least push the asker in the right direction, imo. This is just asking for trouble. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It would appear to me that the correct code would be (**UPDATED** - `===` for `$gender === 0`)

```
if(($birthdate == '' || $birthdate == NULL || $birthdate == '0000-00-00') || ($gender == '' || $gender === 0 || $gender == NULL)){
     echo "Profile Not Complete";
} else { 
     echo "Profile Complete"; 
}
```

This is saying

```
if (birthdate is '' OR NULL OR '0000-00-00') OR (gender is '' OR 0 OR NULL)
    then the profile is  not complete
else 
    the profile complete
```

**EDIT**
After testing with

```
$birthdate = "1984-01-01";
$gender = "male";
echo (($birthdate == '') ? "true" : "false") . "<br>";
echo (($birthdate == NULL) ? "true" : "false") . "<br>";
echo (($birthdate == '0000-00-00') ? "true" : "false") . "<br>";
echo (($gender == '') ? "true" : "false") . "<br>";
echo (($gender == 0) ? "true" : "false") . "<br>";
echo (($gender == NULL) ? "true" : "false") . "<br>";
if(($birthdate == '' || $birthdate == NULL || $birthdate == '0000-00-00') || ($gender == '' || $gender == 0 || $gender == NULL)){
     echo "Profile Not Complete";
} else { 
     echo "Profile Complete"; 
}
```

I am getting:

```
false
false
false
false
true // $gender == 0
false
Profile Not Complete
```

Comment: Plus one for providing pseudocode, since OP doesn't really show full comprehension of what the code does.

Comment: When I put all "||", it returns profile in complete when the fields have a valid values.. You can give it a try replacing $birthdate and $gender with "1984-01-01" and "male"

Comment: @nodeffect I have to agree. Hmm, that is weird. I'll get back to you in a sec if I find I solution.

Comment: @nodeffect Try that (Triple = for the `$gender === 0`)

Comment: @what I'm not sure why I would need to do that?

Comment: @what Oh cheers, thought you were talking about the code section. :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe it should all be `||` (OR).

If the birthday is empty (`''`) **or** zeros (`00-00-0000`), show an error. The value cannot be empty and full of zeros at the same time (`&&`).

Also, I wouldn't check if the variable is NULL, but rather if it exists, using `if(!isset($var) || $var == ''  || ...)`. Unless you set the variable to NULL (`$var = NULL;`) somewhere or unset it (`unset($var);`), it shouldn't ever be NULL.

---

I cannot comment (too little reputation), so I'll write my comment here.

I believe that with `$birthdate == NULL` nodefect wants to check if the variable is set. Marcos Pérez Gude's code given in his answer will not work if one or both of the variables are not set. It would be better to first check if the variables exist at all. It could be that the script is called directly and no form was sent at all.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution:

```
echo (empty($birthdate) || empty($gender) ? 'Profile Not Complete' : 'Profile Complete');
```

Comment: Well that was a short, clear answer using a Ternary operator. Why don't you expand on this? Wait...You do not have to.

Comment: @Peter_James: actually when i use ternary operator i always think, ahan its reduces my no of line in code... :)

Comment: They are efficient for the eyes and code. (I would have them preferred to them to be called Turnary operators personally, easier to produce jokes with. Because...You Ternary'd me right round baby...does not quite work).

Comment: Should really be: `echo $birthdate && $gender ? 'Complete' : 'Not complete'`. [Don't use `empty` if you really mean `!$var`.](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Answer (score 0):

I had found the actual problem here.

Instead of `$gender == 0`, it has to be `$gender == '0'`. The ' is missing here. When `$gender == 0`, it always returns true. That is why it keeps returning Profile Not Complete.

So, the correct syntax would be like below:

```
if(($birthdate == '' || $birthdate == NULL || $birthdate == '0000-00-00') || ($gender == '' || $gender === '0' || $gender == NULL)){
     echo "Profile Not Complete";
} else { 
     echo "Profile Complete"; 
}
```

For those who down voted this post, please do reconsider. This is an actual problem and might help the others.